# Is it possible to build transactions on model and rollback if the dependent model failed validations?

Tags: codeigniter-4

I have two models A and B. Model B has a foreign key which is referred to A. Now, I was wondering if I could treat model A and model B as database transactions and rollback saving changes from Model A and B if any of the instances of Model B failed validations.

Something similar to DB queries as show here, except with models.
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html